# rm() and detach() in function - not working

Tags: r, function

I have a function, which is supposed to do the following:

- remove a given vector
- unload a given package
- re-load a given package

Here's an example:

```
removeReload <- function(old, new){
rm(old)
detach("package:anypackage")
library(anypackage)
new <- new
}
```

However, this function does *not* remove **old** from the workspace. I also tried this function as `old <- NULL`, but again to no avail.

Any ideas as to why this is the case, and how to get old to be removed?

Thanks!

Comment: what about `remove(old)`?

Comment: Because the function body has it's own scope. Functions aren't supposed to change values of variables outside their own scope. You could possibly use `evalq()` and run the code explicitly in the global environment, but that's generally considered bad practice in a functional language.

Answer (score 2):

`rm` comes with an `envir` argument to specify the environment to remove objects from. The default is the environment in which `rm` was called. Normally, if you use `rm(blah)`, the calling environment is the environment you're working in, but if you put `rm` inside a function, the calling environment is the function environment. You can use `rm(old, envir = .GlobalEnv)`

Beware programming with this function - it may lead to unintended consequences if you put it inside yet another function.

Example:

```
> foo = function() {
+   rm(x, envir = .GlobalEnv)
+ }
> x = 1
> foo()
> x
```

There are more details in at the help page, `?rm`, and that page links to `?environment` for even more detail.

---

Similarly, the `new <- new` as the last line of your function is not doing assignment in the global environment. Normal practice would be to have your function `return(new)` and do the assignment as it is called, something like `new <- removeUnload(old, new)`. But it's hard to make a "good practice" recommendation from the pseudocode you provide, since you pass in `new` as an input... it isn't clear whether your function arguments are objects or character strings of object names.